# Crystal Report Data Source update issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, crystal-reports

We have tried to Add a new field in the existing Crystal Report. The report is using class file as the data source (ADO.net(XML)). We have added new property in the data source class. But the new field is not reflecting in the
Field explorer. We tried to add a new connection for the same but we are getting below pop up.

[image]

Can anyone help me , which file path should I give(I couldn't find any XML files in the project)?
Also rest of the fields are empty here.
Do I need to check the check box here(Use dataset From class)?

Answer (score 1):

Open the rpt in Crystal and do:
**Database, Verify Database...**

That should re-sync the rpt with the data source.

Comment: I've tried Verify Database but it is also showing the above pop up.